# Aromatic rings resized with chemfig

Tags: scaling, chemfig

When I want to reduce the size of a molecule drawn with [chemfig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) I usually put a `[scale=0.xx]` before the argument of the command. However when I deal with aromatic rings this method doesn't work well, in fact only the carbon skeleton is resized: the 'aromaticity' is not and it's also out of center.
 
For example:

```
\chemfig[][scale=0.75]{**6(-------)}\quad
```

gives me:

[image: benzene]

How do I achieve a complete resize?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `\chemfig` command has two optional arguments. The manual says this:

> The `\chemfig` command takes two optional arguments; their syntax is
>   as follows:
>
> ```
> \chemfig[<opt1>][<opt2>]{<molecule code>}
> ```
>
> The first optional argument `<opt1>` contains `tikz` instructions
>   which will be passed to the `tikzpicture` environment in which the
>   molecule is drawn. The second optional argument `<opt2>` contains
>   `tikz` instructions which will be executed when each node<sup>1</sup>
>   is drawn.
>
> <sup>1</sup> These instructions are added to the end of the argument
>   of `every node/.style{<argument>}`. This argument contains by default
>   the following instructions: `anchor=base,inner sep=0pt,outer
>   sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt`.

For aromatic rings you need to use *both*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig[][scale=0.75]{**6(-------)}
\chemfig[scale=0.75][]{**6(-------)}
\chemfig[scale=0.75][scale=0.75]{**6(-------)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have just earned a thank you in my thesis.

Comment: @markellos Glad I could be of help :)