# Bug in \arrow label?

Tags: arrows, chemfig

I am trying to scale a molecule which I have as a label over an arrow in a reaction. For some reason, it seems I can't do it and I always get the following error:

> `Argument of \CF@chemfig@i has an extra }.`

Does anyone know how to scale it? Thanks.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
\chemfig{A}
\arrow{->[\chemfig[scale=0.5][scale=0.5]{**6(------)}]}
\chemfig{B}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Comment: You cannot nest arguments in square brackets. Put the entire label in a pair of braces.

Comment: @tohecz I guess the double argument is there on purpose: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149290

Comment: @cgnieder Oh my, ok, I got it.

Comment: @tohecz Yes. Exactly. Since it is an aromatic ring, both scales must be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to cgnieder. A pair of braces solved the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
\chemfig{A}
\arrow{->[{\chemfig[scale=0.5][scale=0.5]{**6(------)}}]}
\chemfig{B}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```