# Fail to pass arguments to orbital module of chemmacros when used inside chemfig

Tags: chemfig, optional-arguments, chemistry, chemmacros

While illustrating atomic orbitals for 1,3-butadiene guided by examples in [`chemmacros`' manual](http://ctan.altspu.ru/macros/latex/contrib/chemmacros/chemmacros_en.pdf#page=38), I receive the following error:

`Argument of \orbital has an extra }. }`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
    \chemsetup{modules = all}
    \chemsetup[orbital]{overlay}
\usepackage{chemfig}
    \setchemfig{
        atom sep = 2.5em
    }

\begin{document}

\chemfig{
    \orbital{p}
    -[:30]\orbital{p}
    -[:-30]{\orbital[phase=-]{p}}
    -[:30]{\orbital[phase=-]{p}}
}

\end{document}
```

`pdflatex` produces the following [incorrect] structure:

[image: Defected structure of 1,3-butadiene]

The same error occurs for the examples from the manual where optional arguments are passed to `\orbital[...]{...}` inside `\chemfig{...}`. I'm using fully updated TeXLive 2018.

#### Update (2019-10-19)

I tried the above MWE again and it compiles as expected using `chemfig` v1.41 from TeX Live 2019, so the problem seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Empirically I found out that putting *arguments* inside `{...}` (and not entire `\orbital[...]{...}` command) solves the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
    \chemsetup{modules = all}
    \chemsetup[orbital]{overlay}
\usepackage{chemfig}
    \setchemfig{
        atom sep = 2.5em
    }

\begin{document}

\chemfig{
    \orbital{p}
    -[:30]\orbital{p}
    -[:-30]\orbital[{phase=-}]{p}
    -[:30]\orbital[{phase=-}]{p}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: 1,3-butadiene]

I'm still not sure what caused the former solution to stop working; maybe it has something to do with the recent `chemfig` update.

Comment: Are you saying that in some older version of chemfig the MWE in your question worked, but now you had to switch the order of {}? Btw. it somehow reminds me this bug https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156547/bug-in-arrow-label

Comment: @pisoir About an year ago I remember using the examples for orbitals from `chemmacros`'s manual and I didn't encounter any issues.