# Chemfig - Scaling benzene rings

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig, scaling

Usually, when I work with chemfig, I scale down all structures to 80% their default size by putting `\setchemfig{atom style={scale=0.8}}` into the preamble, which usually works great.
Now I just started working on a chapter on benzene derivatives, and I noticed that whatever I do, the arc inside the molecule is not being resized, and is offset to the side.

I did find [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149290/aromatic-rings-resized-with-chemfig) question which perfectly describes my problem, however the answer given there does not work for me and I'm not allowed to comment yet.

This is what seems to have worked eight years ago

```
\chemfig[scale=0.8][scale=0.8]{**6(------)}
```

however it just gives me an error: Undefined control sequence. \CF_currentstringangle

Does anyone know a solution that works currently? Can't imagine there isn't one, but I'm not great with TiKZ so that's probably why I haven't found it.

Answer (score 3):

What had been two optional arguments to the `\chemfig` macro in the past, has been changed to different options that can be stated in the `\setchemfig` macro.

Originally, the first optional argument of the `\chemfig` macro contained options that were passed to the `tikzpicture` environment, while the second optional argument contained options to be executed when each node was drawn.

Today, however, the options for the `tikzpicture` enviroment can be defined using the option `chemfig style`, while the options for the nodes are defined using `atom style`.

To scale benzene rings, you still need to define both options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\setchemfig{chemfig style={scale=0.5}, atom style={scale=0.5}}

\begin{document}
  \chemfig{**6(---C----)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also apply the options directly to the `\chemfig` macro:

```
\chemfig[chemfig style={scale=0.5}, atom style={scale=0.5}]{**6(---C----)}
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick! Out of curiosity, if I dump both these options into my preamble, are there likely to be complications with other structures?

Comment: Well, they would be applied to all `\chemfig` macros then. If you are unsure, you can apply the `chemfig style={scale=0.5}` option only to those `\chemfig` macros that need it.